# When, Then JSON timeout and abort

Tags: jquery, json

```
var data={};

var j1,j2,j3;

$.when(
    $.getJSON("site1.com?something",function(site1){
        data.site1=site1;
        }),
    $.getJSON("site2.com?something",function(site2){
        data.site2=site2;
        }),
    $.getJSON("site3.com?something",function(site3){
        data.site3=site3;
        })
).then(function(){

    console.dir(data);

    });
```

How do I assign the json call to the variables j1, j2 and j3 inside the when and where would I put a set timeout in this arrangement?

```
j1.abort();
```

This would be useful as sometimes what if say site2 did not respond but site1 and site3 did... In the current arrangement above then would never be fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I assign the json call to the variables j1, j2 and j3 inside the when

You can just assign the result of each `$.getJSON` to a variable exactly as it's written:

```
$.when(
    j1 = $.getJSON("site1.com?something", function(site1) {
        data.site1 = site1;
    }),
    j2 = $.getJSON("site2.com?something", function(site2) {
        data.site2 = site2;
    }),
    j3 = $.getJSON("site3.com?something", function(site3) {
        data.site3 = site3;
    })
).then(function(){
    console.dir(data);
});
```

---

> where would I put a set timeout in this arrangement?

If you're asking how to change the default timeout, you can set it with [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) and the `timeout` option, which accepts a timeout in milliseconds. You do not need to worry about timeouts and calling `.abort` on any of the requests, this will happen automatically.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  timeout: 3000 // 3 seconds
});
```

---

Lastly, you seem to want to invoke your callback even if one of the requests times out. That's considered a failure, so the success callback will not be invoked. You need to pass a failure callback to `then`, as the second argument:

```
$.when(...)
.then(function () {
  console.log('success!');
}, function () {
  console.log('1 or more requests failed!')
});
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even know about the ajaxsetup and the then error is smart . I am going to try this and get back to you. (In the mean time I have taken out the most unreliable call and put it inside then instead).